# Add String to End of URL

Tags: jquery

I'm changing my link urls to add www.site.com/index.html?s=234&dc=65828

what I'm getting with this code is: site.com/&dc=65828

```
var target="&dc=65828";
$("a").attr({ 
href: "" + target
});
```

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `href` when you call this code? Could you add an HTML example?

Comment: are you trying to get the values of each variable?

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like this:

```
var target="&dc=65828";
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+target);
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need `.each` on there.  You can reference `$(this)` inside the `.attr` function when the selector returns multiple object.

Comment: jquery adds some awesome shortcuts all over the place.

Comment: @tkone But then he has to pass a function as the second parameter for `attr()`. Much more elegant than this `each()` solution.

Answer (score 3):

This would be the elegant way to solve this:

```
var target="&dc=65828";
$('a').attr('href', function(i, currentAttribute){
    return currentAttribute + target;
});
```

The function you pass as the second parameter will receive the current `href` attribute in its second parameter (I named it `currentAttribute` for better readability). Whatever you return from this function will be set as the new `href` attribute.

This approach works fine on more than one links and does not use an unnecessary `.each()`.

- [`.attr()` with a function as the second parameter in the jQuery Manual](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex-%20attr)
- [Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nuBFz/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't you guys believe in error-checking?

```
$('a').attr('href', function(i, currentAttribute){
    // don't clutter up the global namespace
    var target="dc=65828";
    // if it's already there, don't double-do it
    if (currentAttribute.indexOf(target) >= 0){
        return currentAttribute;
    }
    // if we've got a query string already
    if (currentAttribute.indexOf('?') >= 0){
        return currentAttribute + '&' + target;
    }
    // if we've not got a query string yet
    return currentAttribute + '?' + target;
});
```

Comment: well, when someone scrapes the questions code snippet, they'll be grateful I suppose. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple of things.

First:

`href: ""+target`

Will set your link to be only:

`&dc=65828`

You'll need to something like:

`$('a').attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+target);`

But that's assuming that `?s=234` is already on the end of the link.  If not you'll need to add that too.

Answer (score -1):

**Check this out this is will give the exact match result**

```
 $('a').append(function(){
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+target);
            });



    $('a').html(function(){
                $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href')+target);
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var target="&dc=65828",
    $link = $("a");

$link.attr('href', $link.attr('href') + target);
```

Comment: No, this would reset all links on the page to point to `&dc=65828`